# Apple Mach-O Link Error with curses.h

Tags: c, curses

I've been getting this error numerous times in my program. I've simplified things down a bit to illustrate the basics and am still getting errors. I was told that I needed to add this library file to my project for it to work (libncurses.dylib) and it did solve some problems, but not this one.

Here is my code:

// screen.h

```
#ifndef screen_h
#define screen_h

#define MAC  1
#define WIN  2
#define LNX  3

#ifdef PLATFORM 
#undef PLATFORM 
#endif

#define PLATFORM MAC

void screen_erase();

#endif
```

// screen.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "screen.h"

#if PLATFORM == MAC

#include <curses.h> 

void screen_erase(){
    erase();
}

#endif
```

// main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>
#include "screen.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    screen_erase();
}
```

And here's the error I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "screen_erase()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

What's going on here?

Comment: You should probably show the compilation of each file and the link line.  As diagnosed by Joachim, you appear to be calling a C function without telling the C++ compiler it is a function with C linkage - `extern "C" void screen_erase(void);`.  And since that is not understood by the C compiler, you're going to have to work around that too.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you mix two different languages: C and C++.

In the `screen.h` header file, change the declaration to this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void screen_erase();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

That tells the C++ compiler to not do [*name mangling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) on the `screen_erase` function name.